# How to format a date in React

Tags: javascript

How do I format a date in React?

The date comes in the form `<pubDate>Thu, 22 Mar 2018 14:11:40 GMT</pubDate>`.

I would like to display only `22 Mar 2018`.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.posts.map(function(item, i) {
          return (
            <li key={item.guid}>
              <time className="MediumPost-time">{item.pubDate}</time>
            </li>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

**Edited**
After installing Moment.js with `npm install moment --save`, I used it successfully this way:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment'

class PrettyDate extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <time className="MediumPost-time">{moment(item.pubDate).format('ll')}</time>
    )
  }
}

export default PrettyDate;
```

Comment: Is `<pubDate>Thu, 22 Mar 2018 14:11:40 GMT</pubDate>` a string or what is it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React really, you format it as you would in JS. That looks like a string, so easiest way to do would be to use `moment.js` to parse that string into a Date and then use `moment(date).format(DD MMM YYYY)` to format it back to your desired format

Comment: Thanks, I used moment.js indeed and worked very well

Answer (score 2):

A no-lib-dependent JavaScript solution is `item.pubDate.split(" ").slice(1, 4).join(" ")` but you might consider using [moment](https://momentjs.com/) if you already have it installed.

Answer (score 1):

you can format the date like that.

```
function myDate() {
  const date = new Date(2018,3,22);
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
  const day = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
  

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{day}</span>
      <span>{month}</span>
      <span>{year}</span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default myDate;
```